# How to Hide or secure PhoneGap Source Code from the Android apk

Tags: android, cordova, apk, phonegap-build

I'm developing one application on Android using PhoneGap. 
I will be giving this applications to some of my friends. But I dont 
want them to see the Source Code (html, css, and .js files).

Is it any way to Hide or secure this source code from the .apk files ?

Hope to get an answer.

Regards,

Raj

Answer (score -1):

You could use an Obfuscator like ProGuard - that makes yor code sensless for readers and a nice side effect is that it also minifies your code